Dificult multiple replaces
I'was trying to pack all required replaces in a sole line with jrepl, this is the code I've now:
call "jrepl.bat" "\xE2\x80\x9D \xE2\x80\x9C" "\x22\x22 \x22\x22" /x /l /t " " /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -
call "jrepl.bat" "\xE2\x80\x93 \xE2\x80\x94" "- -" /x /l /t " " /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -
call "jrepl.bat" "\xE2\x80\x99" "'" /x /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -
call "jrepl.bat" "\xE2\x84\xA2" "(TM)" /x /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -
call "jrepl.bat" "\xC2\xB0" " grados" /x /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -
call "jrepl.bat" "\xC3\xA1 \xC3\xA9 \xC3\xAD \xC3\xB3 \xC3\xBA \xC3\xB1" "a e i o u n" /x /l /t " " /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -
call "jrepl.bat" "\xC3\x81 \xC3\x89 \xC3\x8D \xC3\x93 \xC3\x9A \xC3\x91" "A E I O U N" /x /l /t " " /f "%Curdir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -

And the following is the code I what the above to be replaced by.
The purpose is to make a faster and cleaner search/replace code.
set "reemplazos=\xE2\x80\x9D \xE2\x80\x9C=\x22\x22 \x22\x22#\xE2\x80\x93 \xE2\x80\x94=- -#\xE2\x80\x99='#\xE2\x84\xA2=(TM)#\xC2\xB0= grados#\xC3\xA1 \xC3\xA9 \xC3\xAD \xC3\xB3 \xC3\xBA \xC3\xB1=a e i o u n#\xC3\x81 \xC3\x89 \xC3\x8D \xC3\x93 \xC3\x9A \xC3\x91=A E I O U N"

Character '#' <- is used to separate each search/replace content in the string reemplazos.
call "jrepl.bat" "%reemplazos%" "$txt=$0.replace(/(?<=\#)?([^#]+)(?=\#)?/g,function(m,g1){return g1.split('=')[1]})" /jq /t "#" /x /f "%CurDir%\%marca%Consolidado-OK.csv" /o -

I always get the error:
JScript runtime error: Mismatched search and replace /T expressions

